# How can i call multiple function in reactj web app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is it possible to call one more function called `getClickCount()` during onClick() in reactjs web app ? How can i achieve in ES6 way ? I have tried below, but throws error..

```
const getClickCount = (id) =>{
    console.log(id);
    const params = {
      id: id
    }
  }




<div className='blogArea'>
    {!results.length && (<div className="noSearchData"><Wave text="Sorry, we couldn't find any results..!" /></div>)}
      {results.map(({ id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails, reactCode }) => (
        <a key={id}>
          <div className='blogImageSection'
          onClick={
            () =>
             getClickCount(),
              navigate("blogDetails", {
                state: { id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails, reactCode }
              }) 
            }
          >
            <img alt="id" src={photo} className="mainblogImage"/>
            <div key={id} className='dataArea'>
              <span className='dataDate'>{date}</span>
              <span className='tags'>cypress</span>
              <h3>{heading}</h3>
              <p className="textElipsis">
                Best heading added here.
                The most relevant data added here.
                Greatest of all time. Wont be a good idea
                play here always.This to again adding most of the
                details to the react page. Successfully.
                     <code>
                        {reactCode}
                     </code>
              </p>
              <a href="_blank" className="readmoreLink">
                Read more →
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include brackets to your anonymous function `() => {}` and place both functions in there.

```js
onClick={() => {
  getClickCount();
  navigate("blogDetails", { state: { id, date, photo, heading, blogDetails, reactCode } }) 
}}
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate you help, accepted and upvoted